# Diagonal and anti-diagonal integral matrices: a special decomposition

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Suppose we have a $3\times 3$ non-singular anti-diagonal matrix with integral entries:

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & a\\ 0 & b & 0\\ c & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} , \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (a, b, c \in \mathbb Z -\{0\})$

1. Under what conditions there is a non-singular matrix $P$ with rational entries such that $P^t A P$ is a diagonal matrix with integral entries, i.e,

$P^{t} A P = \begin{pmatrix} r & 0 & 0\\ 0 & s & 0\\ 0 & 0 & t\end{pmatrix} , \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (r, s, t \in \mathbb Z -\{0\}) ?$

2. Moreover, suppose such matrix $P$ exist. For a given matrix $A$, how can we effectively determine an example of $P$ (up to multiplication by a rational number)? I am more interested in question 2. Since we have diagonal and anti-diagonal matrices I thought the computation would be easy. But it seems more complicated than it looks.

Answer (score 2):

The necessary and sufficient condition is $a=c$.

If a desired $P$ exists, then $P^tAP$ is a diagonal matrix and hence symmetric. Therefore $A$ must be symmetric too and $a=c$.

Conversely, if $a=c$, let $P=\pmatrix{1&0&-1\\ 0&1&0\\ 1&0&1}$. Then $P^tAP=\operatorname{diag}(2a,\,b,\,-2a)$ will satisfy your requirement.

Comment: That is very interesting. Thank you. How did you get $P$? By direct computation? Your answer solves both the problems. A more intricate question is: suppose I want a prescribed result for a given $A$ (with, say, $a=1 , b=-2, c=1$). So, we want $P^t A P$ of the form $diag(k, -k, -2k)$ with $k$ a positive integer. Can we still find $P$? These are not random values, of course, but values I suspect the problem has a solution. I don't know an easy algorithm to compute $P$. By the way, there are likely other values of $P^t A P$ for the same given $A$. Another example is $diag(k, -k, -76k)$.

Comment: @Steve The columns of $P$ in my answer are just eigenvectors of $A$. If you want $P^t AP$ to be a prescribed diagonal matrix $D$, there are at least two additional *necessary* conditions to satisfy. First if $P^tAP=D$, then $\det(D)/\det(A)$ must be the square of a rational number because it is $\det(P)^2$.

Comment: Second, Sylvester's law of inertia states that the number of positive (resp. negative) eigenvalues in both matrices must be equal. So, if $b,k>0$, it is impossible that $P^tAP=D=\operatorname{diag}(k,-k,-2k)$, because $A$ has two positive eigenvalues but $D$ has only one. However, if the eigenvalues of $D$ and $A$ have identical signs, the order of three diagonal entries in $D$ are unimportant, because you can always use a permutation matrix to rearrange them.

Comment: I am not sure if the above necessary conditions are also sufficient, though.

Comment: I see, there is a rigidity on the signs of the diagonal matrix due to Sylvester's law. Thanks a lot, your answer was very helpful.